# CSS box-shadow issues

Tags: firefox, opera, gecko, css

I'm building this page: http://ss.rsportugal.org/

As you can see, there are two 10 pixel shadows in the page. One just bellow the menu and the other just above the footer bar.
These shadows are made using `box-shadow: 0 0 10 rgba(...);`

It works as expected in WebKit engine and for some reason that I am unable to figure out and I could use some fresh eyes on this, Gecko and Opera add 5 extra pixels to `#header` width and not to `#footer-container`, making a horizontal scrollbar appear on the body. Also works fine if I remove the box-shadow but I kind of want to keep it. ):

Comment: Have you tried putting an "!important" on your margin declaration?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because youve set the width to 100% so after the box-shadow is added its 100%+10px (the 10px beign divided between the two sides). If you used `position:fixed;` on the header as well you wouldnt have the issue. Its doing the same thing in Safari by the way, so webkit IS effected. What you could do is wrap them in a container and set that to 100% with `overflow:hidden` then on the inner element make it also 100% with the box shadow as desired.. this way it will get clipped off the left/right sides.

Something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #header {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
  }
  #header-inner {
     width: 100%; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
</style>
<div id="header">
<div id="header-inner">
    <div id="logo">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="menu-background"></div>
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is displaying fine on OSX Safari 5, I don't know about the windows version though. Anyway, I've changed to 'position: fixed', because this was the intended way, but I'm sleepy. Still, it works fine on webkit and gecko but still does the same thing on Opera. I didn't really want to add another div, but I guess I'll have to do it. ):

Comment: Opera was caching the pre-fixed page, so please ignore what I said about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking box-sizing property.

Webkit uses different box-model for box-sizing than FF. IE differ from both.

Ensure you declare the same kind for all browsers, and everything should be processed in the same box-model, thus, not making any disgusting surprises.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already fixed the site, but it sounds like this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446693) that I landed the fix for last week (so the fix should be in Firefox 4 beta 8, though we haven't shipped beta 7 yet).

Comment: Well, Opera still has this issue, but I think I'll just add another wrapper DIV like prodigitalson suggested.

Comment: Please disregard my last comment. Opera was caching the pre-fixed page.